# Open3D background image

Tags: python, open3d

I am using open3d to read point cloud and want to achieve the effect of augmented reality visualization. I want to use the image obtained by the camera as a background. Is there any way to put a background image behind a point cloud in visualizer window?

I saw function set_background(color, image=None) in documentation, but it returns me an error
*'open3d.cpu.pybind.visualization.Visualizer' object has no attribute 'set_background'* .

This is my code.

```
mesh_path = 'BunnyMesh.ply'
mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(mesh_path,True)

bg_image = o3d.io.read_image("dog.jpg")

vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
vis.create_window(window_name='Augmented Reality', width=800, height=600)
vis.add_geometry(mesh)

vis.set_background([0,0,0,0], image=bg_image)

vis.run()
vis.destroy_window()
```

Comment: Hi. Would it be too slow to maybe generate a point cloud and add the point cloud itself as background? If this is the case, Since I am not familiar with python API, I will try to come up with something.